# How to solve the npm install with chromedriver err on m1

Tags: npm, apple-m1

my history:
installed node,npm with homebrew
changed npm-global path(~/.zshrc)
installed globally vue, @vue/cli, @vue/cli-init, cordova

and then ....
I pull my Cordova with vue2.x project at Github and tried to install npm lib in the project.
but
the err happen
I have no idea....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qavOO.png)

Comment: You can upload images in stackoverflow too,  so use that feature for high-response rate please.

Comment: do you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I finally solved this issue  by updating the chrome driver freedommmm!!!  Here my suggestion:: https://m.blog.naver.com/suyoungpk/222312061339